# Where can I find changelog of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, release, changelog

I would like to see list of changes that were made in every version of JavaScript. I would also be interested in what is planned to be added in JavaScript and when a new realease is planned.

Do you know any site where this info can be found?

Thank you

Comment: It would be cool to see an exact revision/feature history. Like, did `for()` come before, after or along with `while()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The standard it is based around: Ecmascript specs: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm
2. Firefox specifics:
   MDC javascript docs including differences in javascript versions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript
3. IE specifics: MSDN library, scripting area: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729665(v=VS.94).aspx

Comment: The only comparison/changelog you should care about are the differences between ES3 & ES5. Also can you find any information/changelogs for chrome/safari/opera ?

Comment: Where are the differences between the versions?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is a dialect of ECMAScript, have a look at the [Wikipedia page of ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) for a version history. You can find the full documentation on the [official ECMAScript page](http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php).